# JAR file fails to run due to JFrames or ActionListener or the enum

Tags: java, browser, actionlistener, executable-jar

```
// Java Program to Launch the browser 
// and open a specific URI 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.net.*; 


public class WOAH extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
        //Creates a list of constants,,,, these are the names
    private enum Actions {
    Open,
    Close
  }
  
    // frame 
    static JFrame f; 
    
    public static void main(String[] LOLZ){
 
        desk d = new desk(); 
  
        // create a frame 
        f = new JFrame("Nudes"); 
  
        // create a panel 
        JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
  
        // create a button 
        JButton b = new JButton("LUNCH"); 
        JButton c = new JButton("CLOTHS");
        
        //sets value for Command name
        b.setActionCommand(Actions.Open.name());
        c.setActionCommand(Actions.Close.name());
  
        // add Action Listener 
        b.addActionListener(d); 
        c.addActionListener(d);
  
        p.add(b); 
        p.add(c);
        f.add(p); 
        f.setVisible(true); 
        f.setSize(200, 200);        
    }
    
        // if button is pressed 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        try { 
            if (e.getActionCommand() == Actions.Open.name()) {
                
            // create a URI 
            URI u = new URI("www.geeksforgeeks.org"); 
  
            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop(); 
            d.browse(u); 
            }
            else if (e.getActionCommand() == Actions.Close.name()) {
            System.exit(0);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception evt) { 
        } 
    }
}
```

I have two sets of code in this set that I am trying to run, for simplicity sake I deleted the lines that ran which use a JOptionPane method.

My goal is to generate a JAR file but in this line of code I am not sure what the incompatibility is. Could it be the enum list or Action$ list that are saved to an external file? or is it the ActionListener? does anyone have any advice?

The code runs fine outside of the JAR configuration

Comment: Better you put the error message here as well. That will make it easier to give a specific answer.

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't execute. I thought it might have been the JFrame because of some association to JOptionPane, but that wasn't it since I commented out the part that may have interfered by that pathway

....................I have never used enum or JAR  tools so I am pretty unfamiliar of what is incompatible........................................

I am using the code "jar cfm filename.jar Manifest.txt Main.class" to generate the JAR

Comment: Alright after a little digging, the exception thrown is :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WOAH$Actions
        at WOAH.main(WOAH.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WOAH$Actions
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more